# reactjs componentWillMount not calling every time when i open modal

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

i am displaying table data inside modal dialog, when i click table row to edit data it will open another modal dialog, here i am getting row data by using clicked row id inside `componentWillMount()`. but when i close edit modal dialog and try to edit other table row `componentWillMount()` will not called. so edit modal dialog is empty. why `componentWillMount` not calling every time?

Comment: It's possible it's still mounted in the background and only display style changes. Try using a different lifecycle method or provide some code for a more detailed answer.

Comment: Show us some code.

Comment: Thanks @NirH i fixed by using lifecycle .

Answer (score 1):

As [Nir H already mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47286375/reactjs-componentwillmount-not-calling-every-time-when-i-open-modal/#comment81522565_47286375), `Dialog` component mounts into the dom only once, and then after you close it, becomes invisible (by changing the left position to -10000px) but still present inside the DOM.

So its clearly that `componentWillMount` and `componentDidMount` methods will be called only once. If you want to open `Dialog` component with different options every time, you can do the folloving:

1. Save ref to the `Dialog` component instanse in the parent component:

`ref={instance => {this.RowDialog = instance}}`

2. Then you can open Dialog by using it `handleOpen` method:

`onRowClick = (event) => {
    this.RowDialog.handleOpen();
 }`

Answer (score 1):

I used following steps to fix it.

1. i used `{(this.state.open) ? <Dialog open={true} ></Dialog> : null`
2. second step by unmounting the component `componentWillUnmount() { }`

Comment: that can do a job, but still, unmounting the component every time has a worse performanсe compared to use of `handleOpen()` with new options